# Sending an image to Twitter in R using the twitterR package

Tags: r, twitter

I'm fairly new to programming and can't figure out how to submit an image to Twitter using the twitterR package. I want to submit an image from a website to Twitter hourly.

This is my script so far. I need help with the command to send an image to Twitter!

```
library(twitteR)
library(httr)


ckey <- "X"
csecret <- "X"
atoken <- "X"
asecret <- "X"

setup_twitter_oauth(ckey, csecret, atoken, asecret)

tweet("")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a parameter in tweet() and updateStatus() called mediaPath which you can use to submit images. Try something like:

```
tweet("some status", mediaPath = "url-to-image.jpg")
```

Edit: media needs to be local or if it's a URL then it needs to have been uploaded to Twitter, which can also be done with the API, but not through twitteR I believe.

Comment: this works for local files. thank you very much. helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem, please mark the question as correct if it helped.